# Unveiling hidden structures

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, permutations, symmetry

One way to unveil a hidden structure of a undirected graph - given as an adjacency matrix - is to permute the rows and columns until a [pattern with a maximal geometrical symmetry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1987366/seeing-symmetries) is found. (The maximum may be local or global.) The pattern in question is a 2-dimensional one.

Another way to unveil a hidden structure of a undirected graph is to replace its edges by identical springs (that may - unphysically - cross each other in the course of relaxation) and look at the 3-dimensional figure in which the system has reached minimal energy. (This figure may be unique or not. It may have locally or globally minimal energy.) The pattern in question is a 3-dimensional one.

E.g. the skeleton graph of a Platonic solid will "spring" into the Platonic solid itself, thus unveiling its "true nature".

> Do these ways of unveiling hidden structures have names? Which
>   abstract mathematical principles do they follow? What do they have in
>   common or - more generally - have to do with each other?

Comment: Are you using "symmetric" in the conventional sense of "arc-symmetric", or more loosely ("highly symmetric")? In any case, you might want to look into spectral embeddings.

Comment: I meant arc-symmetric. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I replaced "symmetric" by "undirected", because that's why I really meant.

Comment: You may be interested in the paper "Structure Preserving Embedding" (http://www.metablake.com/spe/spe-icml09.pdf), which details an embedding algorithm closely related to spectral embedding and gives visual comparisons of the results. The paper briefly discusses spring-based embeddings. Some of the references might be helpful too.

I'd also recommend reviewing the answers to your previous question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24978. There's plenty there that seems relevant to your current question.